# SQL for searching returns incorrect result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, list, session

I have 3 tables in access database: `Item`, `Recipe`, and `ItemInRecipe` - which contains recipeId and itemId (the items that are in the recipe).

I have this method in my `Dbf` class, which meant to return a list of recipes ids that has all the items from `itemList` in them:

```
 public static List<int> GetTheRecipesIdsWithAllItems(List<string> itemList)
        {
            List<int> recipeIdList = new List<int>();
            string query = "SELECT recipeId FROM ItemInRecipe WHERE itemId IN " +
                "(SELECT itemId FROM Item WHERE itemName IN (" +
                string.Join(",", itemList.ConvertAll(i => "'" + i + "'")) +
                ")) GROUP BY recipeId HAVING COUNT(itemId) = " + itemList.Count;
            DataTable dt = Dbf.GetInfo_fromTable(query); //returns datatable with the information
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                int recipeId = int.Parse(dr["recipeId"].ToString());
                recipeIdList.Add(recipeId);
            }
            return recipeIdList;
        }
```

This is it in my server `WebService1`:

```
[WebMethod]
        public List<int> GetTheRecipesIdsWithAllItems(List<string> itemList)
        {
            return Dbf.GetTheRecipesIdsWithAllItems(itemList);
        }
```

I tried using the method in my aspx page:

```
        public localhost.WebService1 w = new localhost.WebService1();

protected void selectItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> l = GetList(); //gets a list of items names
            int[] recipeIdList = w.GetTheRecipesIdsWithAllItems(l.ToArray());
            Recipe[] recipes = w.GetRecipesByIds(recipeIdList.ToArray()); //returns a list of recipes from their ids
            Session["recipeswithitems"] = recipes;
        }
```

When trying to use the list from the Session, it appeard empty, I changed the SQL many times but can't find the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: **Security Hazard: SQL Injection!** Don't use string concatenation to create SQL statements with your user data, use Parameters instead. (This will also fix the error you're getting now, BTW) For more information, you can read my blog post entitled [Back to basics: SQL Injection](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/)

Comment: First of all, have you check if your query works as expected when executed manually (through some kind of db client)?

Comment: I can only access the query through the server, and it won't let me execute it because it receives a list.

Comment: This [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RNCaZ8Ha) shows that your query works, maybe you could debug C# code and run generated query in dbfiddle?

Comment: I tried it, seems like it should work, but it shows 0 even when there are recipes with those items.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue appears to be a lack of parameterization, which is causing your query to return incorrect results.

First create a table type

```cs
CREATE TYPE dbo.ItemList (itemName varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then pass it in as a parameter. Table types are a little complicated: you need to create a `DataTable` containing the data.

```cs
public static List<int> GetTheRecipesIdsWithAllItems(List<string> itemList)
{
    List<int> recipeIdList = new List<int>();
    const string query = @"
SELECT
  ir.recipeId
FROM ItemInRecipe ir
JOIN Item i ON i.itemId = ir.itemId
JOIN @items it ON it.itemName = i.itemName
GROUP BY
  ir.recipeId
HAVING COUNT(*) = @count;
";

    var dt = new DataTable { Columns = { { "itemName", typeof(string) } } };
    foreach (var item in itemList)
        dt.Rows.Add(item);

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@items", SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            Value = dt,
            TypeName = "dbo.ItemList",
        });
        comm.Parameters.Add("@count", SqlDbType.Int).Value = itemList.Count;
        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                recipeIdList.Add((int)reader["recipeId"]);
            }
        }
    }
    return recipeIdList;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but these features can not be used in this c# version.

Comment: Which features? If you mean the `using` statements you can do a `using` block instead, see edit

Comment: It actually doesn't recognize the `using` at all, even that way. Is there any chance I can make it work in the way I tried, to your knowladge?

Comment: Sorry mistype see edit