# SQL to search for an item that has all values

Tags: c#, sql, list, search

I have 3 tables in access database: `Item` (with `itemId` and `itemName`), `Recipe` (with `recipeId`), and `ItemInRecipe` - which contains `recipeId` and `itemId` (the items that are in the recipe).
For example:

| recipeId | itemId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 |

I want to find the recipes that contains all of the items in a list (for a list that has 6 as the itemId, it will return 1 and 2)

I tried doing it using SQL query with `itemId`:

```
public static List<int> RecipesWithAllItems(List<int> itemIdList)
{
   List<int> recipeIdList = new List<int>();

   // SQL query that gets the recipe IDs that have all of the items in itemIdList
   string query = string.Format("SELECT recipeId FROM ItemInRecipe WHERE itemId IN " +
   "(SELECT itemId FROM Item WHERE itemId IN (" + string.Join(",", itemIdList) + ")) 
   GROUP BY recipeId HAVING COUNT(itemId) = " + itemIdList.Count);

   DataTable dt = Dbf.GetInfo_fromTable(query); //returns the information as a dataTable

   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
      int recipeId = int.Parse(dr["recipeId"].ToString());
      recipeIdList.Add(recipeId);
   }
   return recipeIdList;
}
```

Also tried with `itemName`:

```
public static List<int> GetTheRecipesIdsWithAllItems(List<string> itemList)
{
   List<int> recipeIdList = new List<int>();
            
   // SQL query that gets the recipe IDs that have all of the items in itemList
   string query = string.Format("SELECT recipeId FROM ItemInRecipe WHERE itemId IN " +
   "(SELECT itemId FROM Item WHERE itemName IN (" +
   string.Join(",", itemList.ConvertAll(i => "'" + i + "'")) +
   ")) GROUP BY recipeId HAVING COUNT(itemId) = " + itemList.Count);

   DataTable dt = Dbf.GetInfo_fromTable(query);

   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
      int recipeId = int.Parse(dr["recipeId"].ToString());
      recipeIdList.Add(recipeId);
   }
   return recipeIdList;
}
```

This is `GetInfo_fromTable`:

```
public static DataTable GetInfo_fromTable(string sql)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   OleDbConnection con = Dbf.GenerateConnection();
   OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
   da.Fill(dt);
   return dt;
}
```

Both don't work/return incorrect results.
How can I find the recipes with all of the items?

Comment: What is the expected answer when `itemIdList = {3, 6}`? Is it `{1, 2}` or just `{1}` (since recipe `1` contains *both* items `3` and `6`)

Comment: Just `{1}`, the result should be a list of recipesIDs that contain all of the items

Comment: What happens if a recipe contains `itemId: 7` do you want to exclude it?

Comment: In that case, it will return an empty list.

Comment: Sometimes it return a recipe that has only one item from the list and others that are not in the list. Most of the time it returns 0 even tho there are recipes with all of those items.

Comment: Are there duplicates in the list?

Comment: No, there are not.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, see https://dbfiddle.uk/bp5fKu1h, please show a [mcve]. Full `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data please.

Comment: Also how is this different from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985144/sql-for-searching-returns-incorrect-result

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `group by` plus `having`:

```
  select recipeId
group by recipeId
    from ItemInRecipe 
   where itemId in (list items here)
  having count(1) = (list.Count() here)
```

Code:

```
public static List<int> RecipesWithAllItems(List<string> itemList) {
  if (itemList is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(itemList));
 
  var ids = itemList
    .Where(item => item != null)
    .Distinct()
// .OrderBy(id => id) // ordering can be helpful if itemList is short
    .ToList();

  //TODO: What should we return in case of empty list?
  if (ids.Count == 0)
    return new List<int>();

  // I've hardcoded ids and ids.Count
  // Since I have to call Dbf.GetInfo_fromTable
  //TODO: Try to parametrize the query  
  var sql = @$"select recipeId
             group by recipeId
                 from ItemInRecipe 
                where itemId in {string.Join(", ", ids)}
               having count(1) = {ids.Count}";

  List<int> recipeIdList = new List<int>();

  DataTable dt = Dbf.GetInfo_fromTable(query);

  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    recipeIdList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["recipeId"]));
  
  return recipeIdList;
}
```

If can't use parameters and `itemList` is short, ordering can help optimizing: you will have fewer different queries.

Comment: Proper parameterization would be wise: the fact OP is using some custom function is immaterial. You also have a syntax error, and it seems to not be improving the logic.

Comment: @Charlieface: You are quite right, but here I have to call custom `Dbf.GetInfo_fromTable(query)` and I don't even know if it's possible to pass parameters there.

Comment: I adeed `GetInfo_fromTable`